# What does "on the square" mean in this context?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, lyrics

A recently released song from [Ghost](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OyYA8FlfBd0) troubled me.

The chorus troubled me, since I don't understand what would mean "on the square":

> Are you on the square?
>   Are you on the level?
>   Are you ready to swear right here right now before the devil
>   That you're on the square
>   That you're on the level
>   Right here right now (bis)

I've already seen that phrase used, and inferred from the context it was the square of a chessboard, but in that song, we are talking of the listener, nor a chess piece.

I've also seen it used to point to a square in the meaning of a place, but I don't see how it make sense in that song either.

Could anybody enlighten me on what was meant here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[**To be on the square:** to be completely honest in what you say and do](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/be+on+the+square)

*Square* is often used in idioms that refer to correctness and straightforwardness.  For example, you could get a [square deal](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/square-deal) or you could say that something is [squared away](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/squared+away).

(By the way, *music* is a mass noun, so you can't say "a music".  You have to just say "music" or "a song" or "lyrics".)

Answer (score 2):

On the square and on the level are Free Mason terms.  Meaning that you are being honest and truthful in your answer

Comment: https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/on_the_square